# align picture to vertical middle and horizontal center

Tags: html, css

I have the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv8uN/) I am trying to get the pictures of the cats inside the black box to align perfectly in the center and middle so that there is a black border around the image if it does not fit perfectly inside the container. I have tried a few different methods using `line-height:100px` with a `vertical-align:middle` also `text-align:middle` but none seem to be working.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Pv8uN/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these scenarios, when the width/height of the containing element is known, I use position absolute and margin auto. Give the containing element relative position and make the image absolute. `margin: auto` will force the image to display in the absolute center.

```
.photoContainer img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pv8uN/1/

Answer (score 0):

Or if you do not want to position absolute, try this :

```
.content{
    display:inline-block;
    width:750px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:orange;
}

.photoContainer {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#000000;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.content img {
    max-width:200px;
    max-height:200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

see the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aAMJS/

Answer (score 0):

Without absolute positioning.

Check out this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/Pv8uN/4/)

ADD `text-align: center;` to `.photoContainer`

```
.photoContainer:before
{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

and ADD `vertical-align: middle;` to `.photoContainer img`